# How to add names to teams?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to put them into three groups of two people each. I'm not sure where I need to go from here. I don't know how I can add two people to a group efficiently.

so it should look like this

```
group_one = {'2': dan, '8': tom} 
group_two = {'10': james, '12': emily} 
group_three = {'7': kim , '13': jones}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could slice your list within dict comprehension to create each variable:

```
group_one = {i[1]:i[0] for i in my_list[0:2]}
group_two = {i[1]:i[0] for i in my_list[2:4]}
group_three = {i[1]:i[0] for i in my_list[4:6]}

>>> group_one
{2: 'dan', 8: 'tom'}
>>> group_two
{10: 'james', 12: 'emily'}
>>> group_three
{7: 'kim', 13: 'jones'}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Sacul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199113/7655838) code is fine. But if you want an even smaller solution do:

```
>>> my_list = [['dan',2],['tom',8],['james',10],['emily',12],['kim',7],['jones',13]]

>>> teams = [{i[1] : i[0] for i in my_list[n:n+2]} for n in range(0, len(my_list), 2)]
[{2: 'dan', 8: 'tom'}, {10: 'james', 12: 'emily'}, {7: 'kim', 13: 'jones'}]
```

Now your teams are split and stored on a list of dictionaries.

To have them on different variables like `group_one`, `group_two` and `group_three` use unpacking.

```
>>> group_one, group_two, group_three = teams  # Or simply use the code of teams
```